# segmented image not displayed in flask app

Tags: python, html, flask, computer-vision, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making an image segmentation app which segments image into 'k' colors

the code for flask app goes like this:

```
##not pasting standard starting code
app.config['template_path'] = r'C:\Users\Asus\Documents\deep learning\deep_learn\NOTEBOOKS\app\templates'

def image_return():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            print('address accessed')
            file = request.files['img']
            k = request.values['k']
            print('DONE FILE')
            if not file.filename == '':
                print('FILENAME EXISTS')
                name = secure_filename(file.filename)
                print(name)
                address = os.path.join(
                    app.config['template_path'], 'uploads/', name)
                file.save(address)
                print('DONEEEE')
                img = reader(address)
                red_image, path = main(img, name, k)
                print('image red. and saved to path')
                return red_image, path
            else:
                redirect(request.url)
                return flash('something went wrong try again')



@ app.route('/transformed', methods=['POST'])
def transform():
    red_image, path = image_return()
    return render_template('imagetrans.html', address=path)

### ALL THE PRINT STATEMENTS RAN SUCCESSFULLY AND SAVED THE CONVERTED IMAGE TO THE PATH 

## THE APPROACH I AM USING IS TO NOT DISPLAY LIVE IMAGE BUT TO SAVE IS FIRSTLY AND THEN DISPLAY IT FROM A SAVED LOCATION
```

the HTML goes like this:

```
  <body>
    <center>
      <img src={{address}} alt="display.error" />
    </center>
  </body>
```

the python code for generating images works well

```
def color_reduction(img, k):
    # transform the image
    print(type(img))
    data = np.float32(img).reshape((-1, 3))
    # determine the criteria

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 20, 0.001)

    # implementing k - means
    ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(
        data, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    center = np.uint8(center)

    result = center[label.flatten()]
    result = result.reshape(img.shape)
    return result


template_path = r'C:\Users\Asus\Documents\deep learning\deep_learn\NOTEBOOKS\app\templates\transformed'


def main(img,  filename, k=5, title=None):
    red_image = color_reduction(img, k=int(k))
    path = os.path.join(template_path, f'{filename}_{k}.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(path, red_image)
    return red_image, path
```

the reduced_image is not read in `img` src even after passing correct variable address

I think I am going wrong at the HTML part!

Comment: i know there is a matplotlib approach to solving this , but that is not working out for  me too, anyone who can help me figure that part out are also welcome , but its better we make the existing solution better, since this is almost the end of the project , then I can work on some css after this works out

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what the value for address is in the html, i.e. if you look at the page source what does the address value render as in your browser?

I think this is probably going wrong since it looks like you are passing an absolute filepath to the html whereas really you should pass a path that is relative to the flask app instance.

i.e. if your flask app is in a folder called my_site then to src you would just pass the path from my_site to the image, i.e. `my_site\static\img\img.jpg` rather than `C:\Users\Documents\projects\my_site\static\img\img.jpg`.

Comment: oh yeah i guess you are right , lemme try that!!